# Passing parameters to offline cached pages doesn't work

Tags: html, offline-caching, offlineapps, app-offline.htm

I'm making an HTML5 offline app that of course uses a "manifest" file to tell the browser the pages to download, the problem is when I call a previously cached page passing parameters in the URL it doesn't work...
It works if I include the full length URL with the parameters in the manifest file.
Has anyone had this problem?
Is there a way to surpass this?

Comment: I have the same problem. The question mark will force the browser to connect the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessionStorage. See this example http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_local.